# How to send webcam frames from client to flask server?

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv, flask

I'm using openCV for face recognition and would like to do the same for a client by getting their webcam frames on the flask server side and performing face recognition.

I was able to do it on the server side but I want the client's webcam to be used instead of the server's.

Answer (score -1):

Create a client script and a server script and use sockets to communicate between the two.

`server.py`:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",789)) #Whatever port
try:
   s.listen(1) 
except:
   print("[*]Start the script with more permissions")
   exit(0)
conn , adds = s.accept()
print("[*]Received connection")
while True:
    data = str(conn.recv(99999))  #This is the image you receive
    display_image_on_screen_and_facial_recognicion(data)
```

`client.py`:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket
try:
    s.connect(("0.0.0.0",789)) #Same port as server side
except:
    print("[*]Server is not up!")
    exit(0)
else:
    while True:
        data = capture_webcam()
        s.send(data.encode())
```